# Three.js raycast from camera center

Tags: three.js

i try since weeks to raycast from the centre of a perspectivecamera. without event.client.x and y, because i use the device orientation:

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ); // instead of event.client.x and event.client.y
var direction = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, -1 ).transformDirection( camera.matrixWorld );
raycaster.set( vector, direction );
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);
```

i have a perspectivecamera on (0,0,0) … i use the device orientation instead keyboard and mouse to obtain the Rotation… and want to hit a cube with a raycast sent from the center of my cam. i try a lot of examples for a three.js raycast, but no success.

what the hell is wrong with my raycast????

Answer (score 4):

Use simple:

```
raycaster.setFromCamera( new THREE.Vector2(), camera );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gLbkg21e/

Answer (score 3):

For your raycast vector and direction use the cameras world vectors:

```
raycaster.set( camera.getWorldPosition(), camera.getWorldDirection() );
```